# How to share Internet in VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet

An internal adapter is added to both VM1 and VM2, and a nat adapter added to VM2 for Internet access, can and how the VM1 access to Internet through internal adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand and I'm not an expert. Are you saying that you have two OSs installed in something like Virtualbox and one is using a NAT adapter to access the internet, but the other one is not using a NAT adapter and cannot access the internet? Excuse my confusion, but if I understand, you would use a NAT adapter in both VM1 and VM2 to access the internet. That should give both internet access. I also think it's the default setup to assign a NAT adapter to an OS when you create a new virtual machine. I hope this helps, and sorry if I misunderstand your situation.

Comment: I don't want to add NAT to VM1, but want to have VM1 access internet only through internal adapter.